# Can't set React-Leaftlet Maps CRS using a JSON variable

Tags: react-leaflet

I can't set the crs for React-Leaflet using this code:

```
import CONFIG from 'config/config.json';
.
.
.
.
<Map
   ref={(m) => { this.leafletMap = m; }}
   center={this.props.mapCenter}
   zoom={zoomLevel}
   crs={CRS.EPSG900913}       // This works
   crs={CONFIG.leafletMapCRS} // This doesn't
>
```

Here's my config.json file

```
{
"leafletMapURL": "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
"leafletMapCRS": "CRS.EPSG900913"
}
```

The leafletMapURL config entry works fine but the leafletMapCRS doesn't work for some reason.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`CRS` is an object with some properties. In your `config.json` you are making it a string. So what you need to do to make this work is to remove `""` and then import CRS from `'leaflet'`. After you do that you will see that you have to make your file a `.js` instead of `.json` to be able to import `CRS`.

therefore you would have:

```
import { CRS } from "leaflet";

export const config = () => {
  return {
    leafletMapURL: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    leafletMapCRS: CRS.EPSG900913
  };
};
```

and then:

```
import { config } from "./config";
...

 function App() {
  const bounds = [[-26.5, -25], [1021.5, 1023]];
  const configs = config();

  return (
    <Map
      center={[0, 0]}
      zoom={0}
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      crs={configs.leafletMapCRS} // This works
    >
      <ImageOverlay
        url="https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/uqm_map_full.png"
        bounds={bounds}
      />
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Last but not least are you sure you can use `CRS.EPSG900913`? as the available reference systems are described [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#crs) and `CRS.EPSG900913` is not included there.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-set-react-leaftlet-maps-crs-using-a-json-variable-gg96g?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the response Kboul.  Is there no way to read the CRS string from the JSON file and convert it to an object.  I have the: import { CRS } from "leaflet"; in my file I forgot to show that in the sudo code.

Comment: No. there is no way because you need to import CRS and then stringify it but when using json as a file extension you cannot import a module so I do not see a way that can be done. CRS is an object and the only way to include it in the config file is to make it a function as I described above. Please accept the answer if it helped you.